# AutoIncrement Value in Table for each Value on Other column

Tags: postgresql

I am planning to write a audit table to have audited data for the items based on its version

I want to auto increment the version for each item id.

For example my data looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE item_audit (
    item_id         VARCHAR(10),
    version         INT not null,
    value           TEXT not null,
    CONSTRAINT item_audit_pkey PRIMARY KEY (item_id, version)

);
```

```
item_id         |   version       |   value              |
      1         |       1         |       value11        |
      1         |       2         |       value12        |
      1         |       3         |       value13        |
      1         |       4         |       value14        |
      2         |       1         |       value21        |
      2         |       2         |       value22        |
      3         |       1         |       value31        |
      4         |       1         |       value41        |
```

How do I make sure sure that version auto increments based on item_id
Are there any inbuilt procedures in Postgres

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a [`trigger`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html) might be what you're looking for.

First you need a function to increment your version based on `item_id`. Something like ..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_version() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE i INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT max(version) FROM item_audit 
  WHERE item_id = NEW.item_id INTO i;
  NEW.version = COALESCE(i,0)+1;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Then attach this function to the table

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_version
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON item_audit
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE increment_version();
```

After that, everytime you insert a new record into `item_audit` the function will be executed:

```
INSERT INTO item_audit (item_id, value) VALUES 
(1,'value11'),(1,'value12'),(1,'value13'),(1,'value14'),
(2,'value21'),(2,'value22'),(3,'value31'),(4,'value41');

SELECT * FROM item_audit;

 item_id | version |  value  
---------+---------+---------
 1       |       1 | value11
 1       |       2 | value12
 1       |       3 | value13
 1       |       4 | value14
 2       |       1 | value21
 2       |       2 | value22
 3       |       1 | value31
 4       |       1 | value41
(8 Zeilen)
```